# How to induce some function when onmouseleave and also click the left mouse button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got code like below:

Now I would like to add functionality that increase the counter not only when I leave the box/square, BUT ALSO click the left mouse button outside the box/square. So the counter will be increasing only when the mouse leave the box/square and also click outside of the box/square.

```js
var counter = 0;

function myLeaveFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter += 1;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseleave="myLeaveFunction()">
  <p>onmouseleave: <br> <span id="demo">Mouse over and leave me AND CLICK OUTSIDE THE BOX!</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Off topic: You shouldn't have JavaScript in your markup if you don't have to. Use jQuery's `on()` instead. You can pass multiple events to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean to check if mouse had left the div and bind a click handler to the document:

```
var counter = 0;
var mouseLeft = false;
function myLeaveFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter+=1;
    mouseLeft = true;
}

function clickBody() {
    if (mouseLeft == true)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter+=1;

    mouseLeft = false;
}
document.onclick = clickBody;
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will add an event listener to the `body` when the mouse leaves the box and will increase the counter when a `click` event occurs. The new event listener is then removed:

```js
var counter = 0;

function myLeaveFunction() {
 document.body.addEventListener("click", myClickHandler);
  function myClickHandler() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter += 1;
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", myClickHandler);
  }
  
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div onmouseleave="myLeaveFunction()" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
    <p>onmouseleave: <br> <span id="demo">Mouse over and leave me AND CLICK OUTSIDE THE BOX!</span></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s30arxkj/10/) if this doesn't work

Comment: event listener is not needed for this

Comment: It is almost perfect but I think that here it is small bug because when I have got mouse outside of the box and then move the mouse into the box the counter increase - it is not correct. Counter should only increase when the mouse is outside the box and click outside the box. Only when the mouse is outside the box AND/&& click outside the box.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Do you mean when the mouse leaves and simultaneously clicks? If so, that would require the mouse to move and click extremely quickly (faster than JS processes events).

Comment: Please include any code in the answer itself, on stackoverflow.com, not only on an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

Once you left the box AND you click outside of it. The counter will be increased.

```js
var showPopup = function (id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

var hidePopup = function (id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}

// Button Click
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = (ev) => {
  showPopup('myPopup');
  ev.stopPropagation(); // prevent immediate close (because button is "outside" too)
}

// Click outside to close popup
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = (ev) => {
  let popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');
  if( ev.path.indexOf(popup) == -1 ) { hidePopup('myPopup') }
};

hidePopup('myPopup');
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='myPopup'>
  <p>onmouseleave: <br> <span id="demo">Mouse over and leave me AND CLICK OUTSIDE THE BOX!</span></p>
</div>

<button id='myButton'>Show!</button>
```

**Take a look**
This may be helful too [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Comment: The counter should increase only when two conditions met. In your solution the counter increase when I leave or click. It should be connected with AND/&&. And only when I click outside the box.

Comment: Answers which explain what changes were made and why are typically better for future readers than those which just show code.

Comment: Check, will do, hold on :)

Comment: @DavidSmith okay just so I understand it right. You want to increase the counter once you left the box. Only once? Because as soon as you left the box once you meet condition 1 and click after that you met condition 2. OR do you want do increase only if you left and clicked. But if you clicked again nothing shall happen. So you have to enter and leave the box again?

Comment: Generally when I leave the box and/&& click outside the box -> the box should disappear. I am doing it for pop up window.

Comment: @DavidSmith updated the code to something (i quess) more you need :)